# How can I soundproof a sliding bedroom door?

Tags: doors

Does anyone could suggest a way to completely soundproof a bedroom sliding door? I am investigating on car door system, when door is almost close at the end, it will push against door frame to ensure no space would appear so that it could become waterproof and soundproof, but deploy this kind of method is very time consuming and high risk of failure rate as there is no commercial available for this kind of door system. Perhaps someone who have such experience could give me some example?

Comment: Is this a pocket door? One that slides into the wall?

Comment: Getting this right will be difficult, and take a lot of design, thought, trial and error. And note that depending on your heating system (forced air?) you may not want that door to be air-tight, and non-air-tight is non-soundproof.

Comment: "Completely"? No.

Comment: Unless you specifically need a sliding door due to clearances, replacing it with a regular door would probably be easier than whatever weird design you end up with. Also, having a heavier door will help. The standard "door" is basically hollow, and transmits sounds much better than a solid door. This won't give you a completely soundproof door, but should help.

Answer (score -1):

Sound or Water "Proofing" is very difficult. Cheap & simple peel & stick Weather Stripping will greatly reduce air (the majority of sound transfer) & water intrusion. But, to get anything close to "Proofing" you need to have precision full contact around the entire door perimeter.

Sorry but, Star Trek was only a TV show. I'd suggest that you [**check with companies like this**](http://wkdoors.com/bulkhead_doors.php) who are the masters of what you're asking & yes you can buy their stuff off the shelf.